# Clicking on a line in TOC takes me to the first page

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, links

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣gestion␣des␣accents␣(source)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣gestion␣des␣accents␣(PDF)
\usepackage[francais]{babel}%␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣gestion␣du␣français
\usepackage{textcomp}%␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣caractères␣additionnels
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}%␣packages␣de␣l'AMS␣+␣mathtools
\usepackage{lmodern}%␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣police␣de␣caractère
\usepackage{geometry}%?????????????????gestion?des?marges

\usepackage{pbox}

\usepackage{graphicx}%?????????????????gestion?des?images
%\usepackage{caption}% package pour centrer le caption d'une figure
%\usepackage{subcaption}


\usepackage{xcolor}%???????????????????gestion?des?couleurs
\usepackage{array}%????????????????????gestion?am�lior�e?des?tableaux
\usepackage{calc}%?????????????????????syntaxe?naturelle?pour?les?calculs
\usepackage{titlesec}%?????????????????pour?les?sections
\usepackage{titletoc}%?????????????????pour?la?table?des?mati�res
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%?????????????????pour?les?en-t�tes
\usepackage{titling}%??????????????????pour?le?titre
\usepackage{enumitem}%?????????????????pour?les?listes?num�rot�es
\usepackage{hyperref}%?????????????????gestion?des?hyperliens
%\usepackage{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}% package pour centrer le caption d'une figure
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\hypersetup{pdfstartview=XYZ}%?????????zoom?par?d�faut
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} %          modifier le style de titre de chapitre 
\usepackage{makecell} % mdifier l'�pisseur des traits des colonnes de tableau
\usepackage{subfigure} %package pour ins�rer les sous figures
\usepackage{wrapfig} %ins�rer une figure dans la marge d'une page
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}  % la profodeur de la num�rotation du document
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    % la profodeur de la num�rotation du document level = 4
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{lastpage}

%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{mathtools} % multiline equation
%\usepackage{algorithmic}

%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{caption}

\newcounter{mycounter}

%%%%  macro dans le pr�ambule %%%%
\makeatletter
\def\captionof#1#2{{\def\@captype{#1}#2}}
\makeatother
%%%% fin macro %%%%

% creer une liste � puce personalis�
\newenvironment {mynumberedlist}{
\begin{list}{\alph{mycounter}.}{\usecounter{mycounter}}
}{
\end{list}
}

% creer une liste � puce personalis�
\newenvironment {listeNumRomin}{
\begin{list}{\roman{mycounter}.}{\usecounter{mycounter}}
}{
\end{list}
}

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\pagestyle{fancy} %D�finir l'entete
\fancyhead {} % on efface l'ent�te
\usepackage{geometry}



% % %mise en page
%\setlength\paperheight {297mm}% la langueuer de document
%\setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}% la largeur du document
%\setlength\headheight {1cm}% la hauteur de l'entete
%\setlength\headsep {5mm}% l'expace entre l'entet et le text
%\setlength\textwidth {152mm}
%\setlength\textheight {240mm}

%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1cm}

%\def\baselinestretch{1.05}% espace entre les lines
% % % % %


\pagestyle{fancy} \rhead{\empty} \lhead{\leftmark}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1cm} \addtolength{\voffset}{-0.5cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1cm} \addtolength{\textheight}{1.1cm}
\def\baselinestretch{1.06}% espace entre les lines


\begin{document}

%%-------------------------page de garde 
\include{PageDeGarde}



\include{Remerciement}
\include{Dedicace}



% %--------------------------------



\newpage

%%%%%%%% Tables des matières%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table des Matières}
\lhead{Table des matières }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\rhead{} \cfoot{ \thepage} \pagestyle{fancy} \tableofcontents
\newpage


%%%%%%%% Liste des figures %%%%%%%%

\nocite{*}
\setcounter{page}{4} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table des figures}
\lhead{Table des figures}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\rhead{} \cfoot{ \thepage} \pagestyle{fancy} \listoffigures 
\newpage

%%%%%%%% Liste des tableaux %%%%%%%%

\nocite{*}
\setcounter{page}{5} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Liste des tableaux}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\lhead{} \cfoot{ \thepage} \pagestyle{fancy} \listoftables
\newpage

%%%%%%%% Liste des acronymes %%%%%%%%
\include{Liste_des_acronymes} 
\newpage

%%%%%%%% les chapiters %%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagenumbering{arabic}    \setcounter{page}{1}


\lhead{Introduction}

\include{Chapiter1}
\include{Chapitre2}
\include{Chapitre3}
\include{Chapitre4}
\include{conclusionG}
\lhead{Conclusion et perspectives}




\nocite{*} \pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{7}
%%%%%%%% La bibliographie %%%%%%%%%%%%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\lhead{Bibliographie}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\include{Resume}

\include{Abstract}\setcounter{page}{11}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't replicate the result. Can you provide a minimal document that replicates the behaviour that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile? Your current code include a bunch of files we don't have. Remove those and present a self-contained piece of code that we can use. Can you do that?

Comment: Going to the first page (Doc-Start) is the default behavior for a missing hypertext anchor.  You can display a PDF as ASCII (parts of it) and find a list of all the anchors names.

Comment: Did you compile twice? Did you get any warnings?

Comment: Can you please post a _minimal_ example? Remove all unneeded packages from your source, the comments, etc. Just a few lines of code that compile and show your problem.